# How to fetch apexlogs using Lightning Web Components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, tooling-api

I am new to salesforce dev, and wanted to know how can we fetch the apexlogs using a lightning component with tooling API?

I found this from the documentation: /sobjects/ApexLog/id/Body/.

But how can we get the "id" of ApexLog in LWC?

In aura components we can do it by force:recordId but how to do this in LWC?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You can do SOQL on [ApexLog](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ApexLog.htm) Object to get the list of Ids. Then each one can be downloaded  using the preferred API.

Comment: Thanks I did the exact thing